# How to understand "A wise man will only be useful as a man...but leave that office to his dust at least"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Others, as most legislators, politicians, lawyers, ministers, and
>   office-holders, serve the state chiefly with their heads; and, as they
>   rarely make any moral distinctions, they are as likely to serve the
>   devil, without intending it, as God. A very few, as heroes, patriots,
>   martyrs, reformers in the great sense, and men, serve the state with
>   their consciences also, and so necessarily resist it for the most
>   part; and they are commonly treated as enemies by it. **A wise man will
>   only be useful as a man, and will not submit to be "clay," and "stop a
>   hole to keep the wind away," but leave that office to his dust at
>   least**...

Can I literally understand the first clause as "if a wise man is a man, then he will be useful"?

Does the second clause make the "not...but..." construction? What does "office" and "dust" mean?

Comment: During his lifetime, a wise man will not be as malleable as clay, which is good for plugging holes to keep the wind out; rather he will leave that role (that "office", of plugging whatever gap the State needs to have plugged) to his mortal remains (his "dust"). During his life he will not be malleable; he will resist the State as a man of conscience, as one who makes judgments and choices for himself.  The phrase "useful *as a man*" refers to the kind of usefulness he will offer: a "man" is defined earlier in the passage; he will be useful "as a man (i.e. of conscience)".

Comment: It might help to clarify the meaning if we reposition the word **only**: "A wise man will be useful *only* as a man..."  In this passage, **clay**, which is formless and can be readily formed, is a metaphor for the opposite of the convictions that a man with backbone, a man of conscience, will have. And the word **man** is used as a synonym for one who is able to think for himself and refuses to shape himself or conform to the will of the State.

Comment: @BenKovitz I've split them to several questions.

Comment: @LeonZero Excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I literally understand the first clause as "if a wise man is a man, then he will be useful"?

Not exactly. In "*only be useful as a man*", the meaning of "*man*" is very precise and is key to understanding what's being said. In that specific use, "*man*" means something like "*morally courageous person*". So in fact what is being said that *if* the wise man is useful (and that allows for the possibility that you may have a wise man who is *not* in fact useful), his usefulness will be precisely because he is a man, i.e. a *morally courageous person*.

> What does "office" and "dust" mean?

Here, *office* means "job" or "role", and is referring to the job or role of "stopping a hole..." which in this context is seen as something quite low and not very demanding in terms of moral courage. And then *dust* means his lifeless remains after he -- the moral being, the man -- has died and departed.

So what is being said is something like this.

A wise man is truly useful not because he is wise, but rather precisely because he *is* "a man", i.e. morally courageous. And an essential part of that moral courage lies in not allowing himself to be moulded (i.e be clay) according to other people's beliefs. Furthermore, he will not avoid difficult decisions by, for example, simply ignoring problems or applying a quick but ineffective fix ("*stop a hole to keep the wind away*"). A moral man would not stoop to do a job that involved such low and dishonorable behavior. Instead, he would rather leave *that* kind of job -- that "*office*" -- to his own corpse, when he had become mere dust.

> Does the second clause make the "not...but..." construction?

I'm not sure about this one. Does the above answer it?